# will socket error be detected across threads?

Tags: c, sockets

I have two threads working on the same socket, one for read and the other for write. The socket is non-blocking and uses epoll. When write encounters error, it will close the socket. My question is, at this point will the read thread return from the epoll wait with error?

Comment: You might be better off with one handler for read/write and then funnel the read and write events to other threads via a message bus for processing.

Comment: To be safe, shutdown the socket for input. That will cause the reading thread's `read()` to return zero as though the peer had disconnected. Then close the socket in the read thread, which you would be doing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is platform-specific, so take this with a grain of salt.

*Generally*, the answer is *usually* yes, but it *may* be no, too.

Closing a socket prevents any further reading and writing on it, so if the writing thread decides to close the socket, the reading thread can't read from the same socket anymore.

This will *usually* cause a read error.  However, I have been informed of cases here and there where this is not always true.  So, best not to rely on this behavior, if you can help it.

Comment: Never seen that in over 30 years on all versions Windows from 3.0 upwards, including several third-party WINSOCK implementations, BSD, SCO Unix, Novell Unix, AIX, HP/UX, Solaris, OS/2, NetWare, you name it. Some of those didn't have threads, of course.

Comment: @user207421 on Windows, certainly not. Closing a socket invalidates all operations on it across all threads. But I've been told on several occasions that this kind of behavior doesn't always work as expected on some 'Nix and lesser-common platforms. But I've never coded for those platforms. Like I said, take this with a grain of salt.